Showing that $\sum_{i = 1}^N \sum_{j = N - i + 1}^N \frac{1}{ij} = \sum_{i = 1}^N \frac{1}{i^2}$ without induction
It's straightforward to show via induction that
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^N \sum_{j = N - i + 1}^N \frac{1}{ij} = \sum_{i = 1}^N \frac{1}{i^2}\text{.}
$$
(For example, given the table
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\frac{1}{1 \cdot 1}& \frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} & \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3} & \frac{1}{1 \cdot 4} \\ \hline
\frac{1}{2 \cdot 1}& \frac{1}{2 \cdot 2} & \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} & \frac{1}{2 \cdot 4} \\ \hline
\frac{1}{3 \cdot 1}& \frac{1}{3 \cdot 2} & \frac{1}{3 \cdot 3} & \frac{1}{3 \cdot 4} \\ \hline
\frac{1}{4 \cdot 1}& \frac{1}{4 \cdot 2} & \frac{1}{4 \cdot 3} & \frac{1}{4 \cdot 4} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
the sum of the lower-right triangle (including the main anti-diagonal) is exactly the sum of the main diagonal.)
However, it seems that this cannot be just a coincidence, and there must be a deeper reason for this identity to hold. Is there a more illuminating way to show this?
